# Is using vue-cli and vue-cli-service a bad practice?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm building an application with vue-cli and I see that webpack config is not explicitly defined in my repo. It's hidden from us (although it can be changed). Default run dev script by vue-cli also use vue-cli-service instead of webpack.

I'm a questionning myself about the consequence of this.

- Are we losing control over the webpack config?
- Does new version could modify the base hidden config without us knowing it ?
- Are vue-cli taking too much space and break some decoupling principle (since it will be more difficult to change from webpack to another bundler for example) ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

(English not my primary language, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

No modern framework's CLI (including Vue) is going to operate *not* according to best practices.

- You can read on how to work with Webpack in Vue here: [Link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).
- New versions with breaking changes are documented like so: [Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html).
- An application built on any framework will depend on that framework, regardless of CLI use. Configurations built from the CLI can always be changed manually.